# write comment on bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a bitmap displayed on ImageView now i want to give a facility to write comment typed by the user on that bitmap.

i tried using

```
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(srcBitmap); canvas.drawText("Hello", 100,100,null);
```

but this is giving me following error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas
>   constructor

later on i want to save this whole image a bitmap

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get your bitmap from? From the exception it means that you are using a resource/asset directly which can not be modified (it is in the actual apk). To avoid this you need to make a copy of the bitmap and use it for the canvas. Here you got some [examples](http://www.anddev.org/how_to_modify_the_image_file-t513.html) to work with.

Comment: Well i am cropping that bitmap and store it in a temp variable after that i tried to create mutable bitmap by copying it but now i am getting NullPointer exception when i access canvas.drawText

Code is ####

final Drawable d = mPhotoView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bOriginal = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
Bitmap bMutable = bOriginal.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true); 
Canvas canvas= new Canvas(bMutable);
canvas.drawText("Hello", 200, 200, null);

Comment: I guess i am pass null in Paint ( last parameter null) which is causing a problem

Comment: Look for a copy.... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

As Moss pointed out, the bitmap needs to be mutable. Here is some source code how you can do it:

```
//first, get bitmap and make it mutable
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
//now, create canvas and paint as you like
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);
//finally, convert back to icon
Drawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), mutableBitmap);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(icon);
```